# Converting parametric to cartesian - $x=4\cos t$ and $y=4 \sin t$ as $x^2 + y^2 = 16$

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

I am asking about converting parametric equations into cartesian equations.

I'm taking multivariable calc course and there is something I do not quite understand among sample questions. (It's in vector-valued function section) 
We are supposed to sketch a space curve which is

$$r(t) = 4 \cos t \hat{i} + 4 \sin t \hat{j} + t \hat{k} $$

I get how we set the first two parametric equations as $x = 4 \cos t $ and $y = 4 \sin t $

The next step is what confuses me; from the parametric equations, we obtain

$$x^2 + y^2 = 16 $$

How is this the case? Why can the solution not be:

$$\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: x^2/4 or (x/4)^2 ?

Comment: $4^2$ isn't $4$

Comment: Might I suggest the use of latex e.g. $\frac{x^2}{4}$ when formatting mathematics!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have,

$$x^2 + y^2 = (4\sin(t))^2 + (4\cos(t))^2 = 16\sin^2(t) + 16\cos^2(t)$$

We know that

$$\sin^2(t) + \cos^2(t) = 1$$

so,

$$16(\sin^2(t) + \cos^2(t)) = 16$$

So, we have,

$$x^2 + y^2 = 16$$

Which can be written as,

$$\left(\frac x 4\right)^2 + \left(\frac y 4\right)^2 = 1$$

If that's what you meant in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Conversely, if $u^2+v^2=1$, then there exists exactly one $t\in[0,2\pi)$ s.t. $u=\cos t,\;v=\sin t$. That is why such trigonometric parametrisation of a circle is possible.